# Incorrect order of *Provider

Tags: json, resteasy

I use resteasy 2.3.6.Final
And met strange issue with JSON parsing.
I send to server the JSON like:

```
{
"prop1": "val1",
"prop2": "val2",
"@Class": "come.home.CommonDTO"
}
```

And have the response:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException - with linked exception:  [com.sun.istack.internal.SAXParseException2; columnNumber: 0; unexpected element  (uri:"", local:"prop1"). Expected elements are <{}commonDTO>]
```

So seems that that Resteasy doesn't see JSON properties.
The most strange thing, that it works it my local PC. Bur is not working at remote tesing server.

I was debuged the code and find out, that for parsing JSON, resteasy uploads the list of MessageBodyReader, like:

```
class: ResteasyProviderFactory
method: getMessageBodyReader
List<ResteasyProviderFactory.SortedKey> readers = 
this.messageBodyReaders.getPossible(mediaType, type);
```

And I have different order of those MessageBodyReaders.

In my local PC is

```
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJacksonProvider
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.json.JsonCollectionProvider
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.json.JsonMapProvider
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.json.JettisonXmlRootElementProvider
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.json.JettisonXmlSeeAlsoProvider
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.json.JettisonXmlTypeProvider
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.json.JettisonElementProvider
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.DataSourceProvider
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.StringTextStar
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.InputStreamProvider
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.ByteArrayProvider
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.FileProvider
```

But in remote server the order is different:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.json.JettisonXmlRootElementProvider
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.json.JsonCollectionProvider
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.json.JsonMapProvider
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.json.JettisonXmlSeeAlsoProvider
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.json.JettisonXmlTypeProvider
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.json.JettisonElementProvider
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJacksonProvider
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.DataSourceProvider
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.StringTextStar
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.InputStreamProvider
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.ByteArrayProvider
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.FileProvider
```

Somehow this JettisonXmlRootElementProvider comes at fist position and breaks the JSON parsing.

I came deeper and foud that Providers are filling in org.jboss.resteasy.core.MediaTypeMap.

They are uploading and sorting:

```
Collections.sort(matches, new MediaTypeMap.TypedEntryComparator(type));
cached = convert(matches);
if (useCache) {
this.classCache.put(cacheEntry, cached);
}
```

But! sorting works correctly, and seems like the registration of Providers is incorrect:

class: RegisterBuiltin
method: registerProviders
Enumeration en = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources("META-
INF/services/" + Providers.class.getName());

And the order of this resources is different in different environments!
So that's the case.
But I have no idea why this order is different...

PS.
In all enviromnents openjdk version "1.8.0_265"

Comment: Are you targeting a specific container? That is a quite old version of RESTEasy.

Comment: It is "legacy" code. Currency the only choice is update Resteasy version.